# Time Formatting in Microsoft SQL Server as AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, formatting

I have a table with `Start_Time` and `End_Time` columns. The data is stored as `123000` for `Start_Time` and `163000` as `End_Time`.

I would like the query to return the values of the time as `12:30 PM` and `4:30 PM`. Is this somehow easily achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of `Start_Time` and `End_Time` columns?

Comment: The data type is char.

Comment: What is the value that represents 9am? 09000 ?

Comment: Yes 9am is entered as 090000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Start_Time varchar(25), End_Time varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('123000','163000'),
('090000','170000')


Select Start_Time = convert(varchar(8),convert(time,stuff(left(Start_Time,4),3,0,':')),100)
      ,End_Time   = convert(varchar(8),convert(time,stuff(left(End_Time  ,4),3,0,':')),100)
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Start_Time  End_Time
12:30PM     4:30PM
9:00AM      5:00PM
```

> **Edit - To Add Space between AM/PM**

You may have diminishing returns with two replace(), the format() may actually be faster

```
Declare @YourTable table (Start_Time varchar(25), End_Time varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('123000','163000'),
('090000','170000')

Select Start_Time = replace(replace(convert(varchar(8),convert(time,stuff(left(Start_Time,4),3,0,':')),100),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
      ,End_Time   = replace(replace(convert(varchar(8),convert(time,stuff(left(End_Time  ,4),3,0,':')),100),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Start_Time  End_Time
12:30 PM    4:30 PM
9:00 AM     5:00 PM
```

Comment: `4:30PM` or `04:30PM` ?

Comment: @Sami Request was 4:30PM

Comment: Oh yes that's true

Comment: Let me clarify that I only have read only access to the DB. So I cannot alter the tables.

Comment: @sccar This does not alter tables.  The (at)YourTable is a table variable and simply demonstrative

Comment: Thanks John. Works like a champ.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti +1 for the faster performing option! ^.^

Comment: One last thing I need to put a space between the time and AM/PM how do I accomplish this.

Comment: @sccar Just one moment

Comment: @sccar See update/edit.   I can't think of a simple way of adding a space other than replace()

Comment: The data in the table is so little that it really doesn't matter it really is working great. Thanks again.

Comment: @sccar Happy it helped then  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a [much slower performing option](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but), you can use `format()` in SQL Server 2012+:

```
create table t (Start_Time varchar(12), End_Time varchar(12))
insert into t values ('123000','163000'),('090000','170000')

select 
    Start_Time = format(convert(datetime,left(stuff(Start_Time,3,0,':'),5)),'h:mm tt')
  , End_Time   = format(convert(datetime,left(stuff(End_Time  ,3,0,':'),5)),'h:mm tt')
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZDSD64086

returns:

```
+------------+----------+
| Start_Time | End_Time |
+------------+----------+
| 12:30PM    | 4:30 PM  |
| 9:00AM     | 5:00 PM  |
+------------+----------+
```

- [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti ^.^

Comment: Actually +1 for the left() rather than the second stuff,  Never occured to me to trim the seconds

Comment: @SqlZim He need space between time and AM/PM :)

Comment: @Sami Updated... and still the slower solution. xD